# Does it makes sense to make atomic a BOOL flag in multithreading programming

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, atomic

I am quite new to multithreading programming and wonder if it is ok or to make a property like

```
@property BOOL shouldDoIt; //atomic
```

which will be used in a loop that is called in the background

```
- (void) loop{
    // ... do stuff ...
    if (self.shouldDoIt) {
        [self doIt];
        self.shouldDoIt = NO;
    }
    // ... do more stuff ...
}
```

and changed in a method called from the main thread

```
- (void) methodCalledFromMainThread{
    self.shouldDoIt = YES;
}
```

Do I ***have*** to make it atomic or it does not change anything?
I know atomic is slow in comparison to nonatomic and my program needs more speed but if not using atomic then doing `if (shouldDoIt){`  might fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is entirely dependent on the answer to the question:

"do you need to run `doIt` exactly once for each time the main thread sets the shouldDoIt flag?"

If the answer to that question is "yes" then your code will not work because the main thread might set `shouldDoIt` to `YES` after you have started `doIt` but before you have reset the flag.

If the answer is "no", in this narrow case, what you have is sort of OK excepting the fact that in a multi CPU configuration, the flag might be cached in such a way that the other thread does not immediately see the change.  So you probably at least want to use [OSAtomicTestAndClearBarrier()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/atomic.3.html) and OSAtomicTestAndSetBarrier() which are as low level, hence as fast as you can get.

However, I'm sceptical that you need to do this.  I think you might find refactoring the design in some way will get better results depending on what you are trying to do in `doIt`, `do stuff` and `do more stuff`.

Comment: If we are using only a **writer** thread and **reader** thread than we don't need interlocked access to variable **shouldDoI** of course main thread must first wait **shouldDoI** to become 0 before set again the **shouldDoI**.

Comment: JeremyP you have made me realize the difference between setting back  shouldDoIt to NO after and before doIt. +1 for OSAtomicTestAndClear/SetBarrier() ;)

Answer (score 2):

On may thread you have an BOOL that you want to set to no after you do some job in back thread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backThreadAction:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


-(void) backThreadAction:(id*)someObject{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //do stuff here

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishBackThreadAction:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

-(void) didFinishBackThreadAction:(id *)someObject{
   //set your bool to no
}
```

Comment: +1 for the code ;)  I suppose I can do the same with GCD (since I am not using NSThread or performSelectorOn... APIs)

Answer (score 0):

Read first the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) from Apple and I think you need an [NSLock](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
but be careful you can get an deadlock.
Good Luck

Comment: I understand that NSLock is an alternative but I think is too much work and I trying to fin out if 'atomic' is just enough when is a single  BOOL flag like this case.

Comment: If you set an property atomic it will have mutex locks on setter and getter. In you case if you set the bool to yes and the go to an back thread and do some stuff, and after you do the stuff you will set it to no I don't see any problem here.

Answer (score 0):

in this part of the code :

```
if (self.shouldDoIt) {
    [self doIt];
```

shouldDoIt being atomic does not guarantee that it is still `true` when you call doIt. You must use a lock to make sure the value did not change after the test and before you actually do what you have to do.

Comment: Not true, if we are using only a writer thread and reader thread!